# Unique link specific to site member on Wix website needed

Tags: html, velo

I have used Wix.com in the past for projects but I am stuck on a particular issue with my current site.

I have a Wix template website with the standard subscription set up for customers. It has the standard associated members pages supporting it. I want to grant each member access to a document (via link) specific to them only and that is private to all other members. Eg:

User 1 link: [www.testweb.com/abc1](http://www.testweb.com/abc1)
User 2 link: [www.testweb.com/abc2](http://www.testweb.com/abc2)
etc

Ideally I wanted a member page containing the link relating to the logged in user.

I tried using the Wix CMS with 2 fields: user email and document link, but can't see how to integrate this into the member page template.

I then investigated using the File Share app. I could fudge it by setting up a hidden folder for each user, which contained a file with the user-specific link. This is not a nice user experience and also the user has to download the file, they can't just view it (is this a wix bug?, just a side comment).

I have some coding experience but I am trying to keep this within Wix's template capabilities as I will be handing this over to someone to run and it just keeps things simple. Wix is the only option for now (for a number of reasons) I am afraid.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, using a standard CMS table - the URLS work.

and much simpler code just filtering the dataset on id.

```js
import { currentMember } from 'wix-members-frontend';
import wixData from 'wix-data';
$w.onReady(async function () {
  let id;

  currentMember.getMember()
    .then((member) => {
      id = member._id;
      $w("#dataset8").setFilter( wixData.filter()
  .eq("userId", id))
// ...
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved my problem! I really appreciate all your help with this

Answer (score 0):

First off all, I'm not at coding expert and have been googling to get this far... perhaps I have answered some of your question and you could help finish it off?
But... so far I have managed this with a backend function, called from a member's area page. Using CMS and pulling the member ID from the current user to fill a table on their member page.

The backend function:

```js
import { sql } from '@velo/wix-data-sql-backend';  //'wix-'  wix-data-sql-backend

export async function getAllMyOrders(userId) {
    try {
        const result = await sql('SELECT orderNumber, orderDate, url FROM testResults WHERE userId = "' + userId + '"');
        return result.payload.data.rows;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Members area page code:

```js
import { getAllMyOrders } from 'backend/sqlFunctions';
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';
import { currentMember } from 'wix-members-frontend';

let myTableData; // Define myTableData in a higher scope
$w.onReady(async function () {
  let id;

  currentMember.getMember()
    .then((member) => {
      id = member._id;
      getAllMyOrders(id)
        .then((result) => {
          if (result === "NORESULTS") {
            console.log("no data");
          } else {
            console.log(result);

            // Assuming result is an array of objects, update myTableData with the result.
            myTableData = result;

            $w("#table1").dataFetcher = getRows;
          }
        });
    });
});

function getRows(startRow, endRow) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (myTableData) { // Check if myTableData is defined
      // Fetch the objects from startRow to endRow from `myTableData`:
      const fetchedDataRows = myTableData.slice(startRow, endRow);
      // resolve to DataRequested object
      resolve({
        pageRows: fetchedDataRows,
        totalRowsCount: myTableData.length
      });
    } else {
      reject("myTableData is not defined.");
    }
  });
}
```

This results in the following:
[image: member page]

My problem is the links aren't clickable in the table. Which is where I could use help, or to make them documents/pdfs from the CMS.
[image: cms]